# How to compare two stat values of the same file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

[Screenshot of the my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOnOF.png)

I am trying to make a shell program that tells me when a file has been created, when it has been modified, and when it has been deleted. I think I can solve this but my only issue is that I cant compare the stat values. It tells me that I have "too many arguments". Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
#!/bin/bash

run=yes

if [ -f $1 ]
then

    while [ run=yes ]
    do

        time1=$(stat -c %y $1)

        time2=$(stat -c %y $1)

        if [ ! $time2 ]
        then
            echo "The file "$1" has been deleted."
            run=no

        elif [ $time2 -gt $time1 ]
        then
            echo "The file "$1" has been modified."
            run=no
fi
done

else
    while [ run=yes ]
    do
    sleep 2

        if [ -f $1 ]
        then
        echo "The file "$1" has been created."
        run=no
fi
done
fi
```

Comment: Use `bash -n yourscript` to test for syntax errors. You might also want to consider running your scripts through http://www.shellcheck.net/ before you post bash questions here. Helps to insure that the challenges you post actually would benefit from human attention. Lots of things can be detected and fixed instantly, and don't need to wait for answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `static -c %y ...` includes spaces, which is what the shell uses to separate arguments.  When you then run:

```
if [ ! $time2 ]; then
```

This translates into something like:

```
if [ ! 2017-09-02 08:57:19.449051182 -0400 ]; then
```

Which is an error. The `!` operator only expects a single argument.  You could solve it with quotes:

```
if [ ! "$time2" ]; then
```

Or by using the bash-specific `[[...]]]` conditional:

```
if [[ ! $time2 ]]; then
```

(See the `bash(1)` man page for details on that second solution).

Separately, you're not going to be able to compare the times with `-gt` as in:

```
    elif [ $time2 -gt $time1 ]
```

This (a) has the same problem as the earlier `if` statement, and (b) `-gt` can only be used to compare integers, not time strings.

If you were to use `%Y` instead of `%y`, you would get the time as an integer number of seconds since the epoch, which would solve all of the above problems.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful! I can now successfully print the messages. However, the script is supposed to stop running when a message has been printed. In my case the script keeps running. Maybe its because of a problem with the run variable?

Answer (score 0):

The code is now working and I thought I would share the final result if anyone wanted to know.

```
#!/bin/bash

run=true

if [ -f $1 ]
then

while [ "$run" = true ]
do

    time1=$(stat -c %Y $1 2>/dev/null)
    sleep $2
    time2=$(stat -c %Y $1 2>/dev/null)

    if [ ! "$time2" ]
    then
        echo "The file "$1" has been deleted."
        run=false

    elif [ $time2 -gt $time1 ]
    then
        echo "The file "$1" has been modified."
        run=false
fi

else
while [ "$run" = true ]
do
sleep 2

    if [ -f $1 ]
    then
    echo "The file "$1" has been created."
    run=false
fi
done
fi
```

Comment: This still has lots of errors that would be detected quickly at http://www.shellcheck.net/. Give it a shot. You'll like it. :)